# Editable Grid: Multiple datepickers

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I'm constructing a view where the user can edit the date of each item for the model `Store` and I'm using JqueryUI datepicker JS.

This is the view (extract):

```
@model IEnumerable<Application.Models.Store>
@foreach (var item in Model)
    {
<input type="text"  class="datepicker form-control"  asp-for="@item.DesignatedDate" 
  name="DesignatedDate" form="@(String.Format("{0}{1}","form",item.StoreID))" />
```

and this is the JS:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $(".datepicker").datepicker();
    });
</script>
```

Since I'm showing multiple Stores in this grid, each one has it's own date to be picked.

**The problem** I'm having is that all the datepickers are linked between each other since each input has:

```
asp-for="@item.DesignatedDate"
```

which translates to:

```
id="item_DesignatedDate"
```

Note: I use `asp-for="@item.DesignatedDate"` in order to show the current date that the Store has registered when the pages loads.

And so, when I change the date of any Store, it will change the date of the first Store, always.

Any idea on how to fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

I just had to add an id to each   in order to be differentiated:

```
id="@(String.Format("{0}{1}","any",item.StoreID))"
```

And now it works.